# Implementing a simple queue in Go using slices

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a very simple queue in Go using slices. This is the code that I have to enqueue five values and then discard the first two values:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var (
    localQ  []int
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", localQ, len(localQ))
    for i := 0; i< 5; i++ {
        localQ = enqueue(localQ, i)

        fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", localQ, len(localQ))
    }

    localQ = dequeue(localQ, 2)

    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", localQ, len(localQ))
}

func enqueue(q []int, n int) ([]int) {
    q = append(q, n)

    return q
}

func dequeue(q []int, s int) ([]int) {

    r := q[s:]

    q = nil

    return r
}
```

Two questions regarding the dequeue func:

1- I'm trying to ensure that the popped items are discarded and garbage collected. Does this function result them to be garbage collected?

2- What are the time and space complexities of `r := q[s:]`? I know there is an array under each slice. Are the array values being copied? Or is it just a pointer being copied?

Comment: Read [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Comment: Why not just use a channel?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer If we use channels, is there a way to perform a "peek", i.e. get the first `n` items in the queue without them being removed from the queue?

Comment: @svakili The expression `len(c)` will tell you how many elements are in a channel, but you cannot inspect the values without popping the values with a receive operation. A queue implemented with a channel has a fixed capacity.  That may or may not be a good thing depending on application requirements.

Comment: @svakili, also note that the functions presented here have no value, as there is no difference from simply using `append` and `q[s:]` directly, and the functions existence is probably a cause of confusion. The behavior of slices is quite simple, and anything more complex (i.e. provides safe concurrency) would probably be better encapsulated in a struct with methods.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this function result them to be garbage collected?

If the application enqueues a sufficient number of elements to cause the slice backing array to be reallocated, then the previous backing array (and its elements) will be eligible for collection.

> What are the time and space complexities of r := q[s:]?

This is an O(1) operation. The operation does not allocate memory on the heap.